# Use rtkit to get content from tickets in Request Tracker

Tags: python

i'm trying to get some contents from tickets with REST api in Ubuntu 16.04 and i'm having truble getting that content using the next code :

```
from rtkit.resource import RTResource
from rtkit.authenticators import QueryStringAuthenticator
from rtkit.errors import RTResourceError
from rtkit import set_logging
import logging
import re
set_logging('debug')
logger = logging.getLogger('rtkit')

resource = RTResource('http://ubuntu/rt/REST/1.0/', 'root', '**passwd**', QueryStringAuthenticator)

try:
   response = resource.get(path='ticket/2')
   myTicket = response.as_object() ## Returns an RtObj instance
except RTResourceError as e:
   logger.error(e.response.status_int)
   logger.error(e.response.status)
   logger.error(e.response.parsed)
```

And the terminal is giving this error:

```
File "LoginQuery.py", line 85, in <module>
   myTicket = response.as_object() ## Returns an RtObj instance
AttributeError: 'RTResponse' object has no attribute 'as_object'
```

Did someone had this problem too?? and know how to solve it??
Help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the package [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/python-rtkit/#read-a-ticket) it seems like the proper way to read the response is to use `response.parsed`:

```py
try:
    response = resource.get(path='ticket/1')
    for r in response.parsed:
        for t in r:
            logger.info(t)
except RTResourceError as e:
    logger.error(e.response.status_int)
    logger.error(e.response.status)
    logger.error(e.response.parsed)
```

Comment: Check the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but i was trying to get the information from the contents separately... and some hours latter i cam with this :

```
try:
response = resource.get(path='ticket/2')
Ticket = response.parsed 
Criation = Ticket[0][12][1]
```

This allow me to get de date when it was created